# Last line not visible

Tags: html, css

I have a website in which the last 2-3 line are not visible due to Footer.

Coding of Footer

```
.footer {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: gold;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.footer a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

Please help me out!

And the last lines coding

```
qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf
 <?php include 'advertisement.php' ?>qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre 
fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre 
fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre
 fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre 
fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre 
fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre 
fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre
 fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre 
fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe 2194916546 6921658cdc 
 fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre 
fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf qdqfefre 
fwefwqedwqe gferfgre 96587 wffdgrf 5582
stackoverflow.
```

Comment: I dont see the problem?

Comment: Are you able to see the last word **stackoverflow** in the website?

Comment: Change order of divs. Place footer div after your main div

Comment: @BabaluPandey Yes I am

Comment: @Chirag the footer is coded in another page. I have included it.

Comment: @Webbanditten sorry sir, I am not able to see from different browsers too. Can you please screenshot it.

Comment: Add `bottom-margin:55px;` to your main div. your problem would be solved.

Comment: Yes @Chirag it helped me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes I do see the problem, top and bottom text got clipped

you can fix this by applying top bottom margin to `main` class

```
.main{
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```